# Paypal Adaptive Live App not correctly working Sandbox OK

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a Paypal app that uses adaptive pre-approved adaptive payments.

The sandbox is performing great, meaning all functions work fine including the below 2 points; however, the Live app is not working properly as per the below.

1. When a user makes a pre-approved payment, for some reason the date of the pre-approval changes. For instance if I make a payment on Oct. 25th, screen 1 shows start date of Oct 26 and end of Oct 27 which is fine, but the screen 2 (to confirm payment) shows start date of Oct 27 and end of Oct 28.
2. Transaction history dashboard of successful transactions not showing on our admin dashboard (althought paypal transactions occurred and were successful) of our website anymore. The dashboard usually shows name, address, and transaction amount of pledgers, project owners. The info is fetched from Paypal and displayed on our admin dashboard

Would you have any idea of what can cause this? The above is working just fine using the Sandbox APP.

Comment: For the sake of providing complete info, the paypal app runs on Ruby

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your question is quite old and there was no response but I'm sure it was eventually sorted from your side. I also see you are based in South Africa. My Experience was that sandbox will work perfectly where currency is set US$ and also using US sandbox email addresses available on developer platform. As soon you go live, Paypal will now detect you are based in South Africa and features like Masspay then become an issue.